# Strategy for version controlling database changes during development

Tags: design-patterns, database, version-control

I am redesigning a CRM tool, of sorts, from the ground up. We are creating the application and the database from scratch. In order for developers to stay out of each others' way, each developer has a local copy of the application's database rather than sharing a single dev database. This avoids the case of developer 1 making a database change that works for them but breaks the application for everyone else until developer 1 checks in their code changes.

At the suggestion of an answer to a similar such question I saw when we were getting started, we are keeping in source control a folder of sequentially numbered SQL scripts. As a developer makes changes to their database, they script out all of their changes into a SQL file and check it in together with the accompanying application code changes. In theory, that sounds good, but here are some difficulties with it:

1. If 5.sql is the latest checked in database change script, any (usually all) developers making new database changes create a file named 6.sql because it's a first-come-first-serve type situation. But there can only be one 6.sql checked in. So you either have to check which files everyone is planning to check in before creating your next SQL file or just before you check in, check what is already there and rename your file to the next one (which is still technically subject to a conflict if two developers are checking in at the same time).
2. When you get latest you have to go run the latest SQL files to bring your database up to date with the latest code you retrieved. This is easy to forget until you run the application and have something blow up. But the bigger problem is it's hard to remember which file you ran last - i.e. which version your database is already on.
3. No merging or conflict detection. If 2 developers are checking in update scripts at the same time, developer 2's scripts could have conflicting changes with developer 1s new changes. E.G. Say developer 2 writes a script to change the Person.ModifiedDate column to NOT NULL, but just before developer 2 checks in, developer 1 checks in a script that changes the name of Person.ModifiedDate to Person.LastModifiedDate. Developer 2 will either just rename their file so the filename doesn't conflict and unwittingly check in what is now a broken script, or will have to follow a protocol that they cannot check in a sql script until applying all of the latest and validating their script. This is a painful process, especially if developer 2 went and applied developer 1's changes, updated their script(s) and then tried to check in only to find developer 3 has now checked in a script.

So I'm thinking of writing a console app that runs before build to grab the script files and run them against the database in order. It would just need to store the last file it ran somewhere so it knows whether there are new scripts to run the next time. That seems like it will fix #2, but does anyone use a better strategy that addresses all the issues? So far we have avoided conflicts by working on unrelated pieces of the application but as we move forward that will become harder and harder to do and the current strategy requires too much developer discipline - know it will end up causing problems.

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html

Comment: Re. #1 and #3:  A version control system is not a substitute for communication among your developers.

Comment: Agreed. But you don't always have the power to force communication or understanding either. Automated control or _simple_ protocols mean less of my time spent trying to explain what went wrong, why, and the need for communication.

Comment: how do these issues differ from changing and committing source code?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you for that link. SO helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called database migrations. You're on the right track. Let me address your issues.

> 1. or just before you check in, check what is already there and rename your file to the next one (which is still technically subject to a conflict if two developers are checking in at the same time)

The first person to push to your integration branch wins, and all others must rename. It shouldn't be a big deal, and you should make sure it's as simple as renaming a file--you shouldn't have to reconfigure other things too. I don't think you should try to avoid this because the alternative is trying to predict which developer is going to finish first which will inevitably cause bottlenecks.

> 2. When you get latest you have to go run the latest SQL files to bring your database up to date with the latest code you retrieved. This is easy to forget until you run the application and have something blow up. But the bigger problem is it's hard to remember which file you ran last - i.e. which version your database is already on.

This is the benefit of having a tool that runs database migrations for you. There are two very popular migration tools out there: [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) and [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/). These tools keep track of which migrations have been run, and you should configure them to run when the app starts up. The tool will scan your directory for any scripts it hasn't seen yet and apply them to the database one by one. It's pretty much what you're proposing to make yourself, but it's already written and mature.

> 3. No merging or conflict detection. If 2 developers are checking in update scripts at the same time, developer 2's scripts could have conflicting changes with developer 1s new changes.

The tool will help you here too. Your integration tests should run migrations on a clean database, and if there are two migrations with the same version number, the tool will throw an error. So the first person to push a version number the tests should pass, and if another person has the same version number the tests will start failing.

Comment: First, thank you. I have two follow up questions after looking at the tools. 1) Let's say you want to rename a table. What steps do you follow to accomplish this. If I execute the rename on my local db and then add the script as a migration, it will try to run the migration and fail because it's already renamed. So it seems like I need to let the migration tool apply it and not actually change the database myself, is that right? I can adjust to that but that leads me to my second question. 2) I've added my `v2__RenameTable.sql` migration and when I build or run the application, the migration..

Comment: ... tool executes the script and updates my db to version 2. Now, (with #1 in your answer above in mind) when I check in, I find that `v2__SomeOtherChange.sql` already exists so I rename my file to `v3__RenameTable.sql`. But my database already has my change applied and tracked as version 2. So it would fail to run `v2__SomeOtherChange.sql` after I get it and it will try to re-rename my table when it tries to migrate to `v3__RenameTable.sql` which will fail because its already renamed. What am I missing?

Comment: The answer somewhat depends on how disposable your local db is. We typically destroy local db and recreate them by running the migrations. This obviously isn't an option if you have important test data in your local db or data that is too big to restore quickly. In this case I would recommend manually running v3 against your database, and manually updating the migration version table (`schema_version` in Flyway) to match the current state of the db with the correct migration names in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

The article provided by Robert Harvey has the answer for your three concerns. The key point here is you need a CI to run the database migration scripts. Your database migration scripts and your application code are in the **same repository and run by CI (Continuous Integration)** together.

Any semantic conflicts you mentioned in point 3 should be detected by failing database upgrade scrips or failing automated tests. You're considering building console app. Generally, it's not necessary. Effectively, your build script running in CI should serve this purpose. Only things you need are making sure the build script in CI can be run in everyone's local, and encouraging developers **run build script before checkin**.

Another concern you have is potential more conflicts by time (more devs). The answer here may be off the topic. However, I think it’s worth mentioning. Try to **separate your systems to different bounded contexts** and make database inside the context. Integrating in shared database is all the beginning of mess.